# Generating hex numbers of a certain range

Tags: bash, shell, hex

I need a simple way to generate a .txt file with a list of semi-colon delimited hex numbers between (inclusive) a certain start and finish value.

For example:

If I enter `0` and `FFF` it would pad the output with zeroes to the largest number:

> 000;001;002;003;004;005;006;007;008;009;00A;00B;00C;00D;00E;00F;010;011;....FFF;

If I enter `FFF` and `1200` it would output those values...etc:

> 0FFF;1000;1001;1002;.....1200;

Any suggestions?  I'm not a programmer so the best, simplest way to do this is way beyond me.

Answer (score 15):

Another Attempt (still needs seq but not bc) - works in cygwin and linux:

```
seq 0 255 | while read n; do printf "%04X;" $n; done
```

The inputs are decimal, but the output is capitalised hex and you can change the digits to show by updating the "04" part of the printf format string

Comment: Just for kicks, "because".... `seq $(printf %d 0xA000) $(printf %d 0xA0FF) | xargs -- printf "%04x;"` in Bash. If you do use Fish like me, it's actually `seq (printf %d 0xA000) (printf %d 0xA0FF) | xargs -- printf "%04x;"` 'cause fish people seem to dislike Dollars for some reason... ;D Maybe there's a better way to deal with bash expansions, my limit on that front was this: `bash -c "echo {$(printf %d 0xA000)..$(printf %d 0xA0FF)}|tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -- printf %04x\\\n | paste -sd ';' -" `

Answer (score 11):

Here's a script that's portable (any POSIX shell will do), should work blazingly fast (no forks to nawk, bc, etc...) and adheres to the poster's spec.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# hexcount -  POSIX Shell script to count from $1 to $2 in hex,
#             separated by ";" and with the precision set to the
#             maximum digits of $1 and $2.
# Usage:      hexcount lo hi
# Example:    hexcount FFF 1200

from=$1 to=$2
if test "${#from}" -gt "${#to}"; then
    format="%0${#from}X;"
else
    format="%0${#to}X;"
fi
from=$(printf '%d' "0x$from") to=$(printf '%d' "0x$to")
while test "$from" -le "$to"; do
    printf "$format" "$from"
    from=$((from+1))
done
printf '\n'
```

Ain't printf cool?

Comment: At present, this is faster to execute in ksh93 (which recognizes `var=$(printf ...)` and optimizes it to avoid a fork) than bash (which doesn't); but that's not easily fixed without reducing portability (as by using bash-only syntax such as `printf -v from '%d' "0x$from"`). It's an outstanding answer nonetheless (and those lone forks, when they do occur, are outside a loop, making them relatively inconsequential) -- and hopefully bash will improve to execute it as efficiently as ksh93 does in the future.

Answer (score 7):

I just like to use simple for loops. You can add as many nested loops as you like for each digit:

```
for i in {0..9} {a..f}; do for x in {0..9} {a..f}; do for y in {0..9} {a..f}; do printf "$i$x$y;"; done; done; done
```

Output should look like this:

```
000;001;002;003;004;005;006;007;008;009;00a;00b;00c;00d;00e;00f;010;011;012;013;014;015;016;017;018...ff8;ff9;ffa;ffb;ffc;ffd;ffe;fff;
```

That was a one-liner, but let me give it some structure:

```
for i in {0..9} {a..f}
do
   for x in {0..9} {a..f}
   do
      for y in {0..9} {a..f}
      do
         printf "$i$x$y;"
      done
   done
done
```

Comment: This always starts at zero. The question also mentions a non-zero starting number.

Comment: This is MUCH faster (seconds vs minutes!) than going `bc` like the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm really late to this party, but here's my uber bash solution. You iterate the value range in decimal and use printf.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( seq 0 100 ); do
  printf "%03X;" $i >> test.txt
done
```

I think it makes sense and fits the brief of the formatting + being simple. Worth noting that you need to adjust the "3" in "%03X" to match the field width you want to print.

Update: you can always over-engineer a thing.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# test that there are 2 command line parameters
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then

  # test that the first is numeric
  if [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2> /dev/null; then

    # test that the 2nd is numeric
    if [ -n "$2" ] && [ "$2" -eq "$2" ] 2> /dev/null; then

      # test that the 2nd is >= the 1st
      if [ "$2" -ge "$1" ]; then

        # determine the field width of the higher number
        ENDHEX=$( printf "%X" $2 );
        ENDWIDTH=${#ENDHEX}

        # Generate the hex sequence
        for i in $( seq $1 $2 ); do
          printf "%0${ENDWIDTH}X;" $i
        done

        exit 0
      fi
    fi
  fi
fi

echo "hex script thing"
echo "usage: script <min> <max>"
echo "script will then print the sequence of numbers in hex, delimited by semicolons"
echo "to output to file use: script <min> <max> >> output.txt"
exit 1
```

update to the update: you can always code golf a thing too. printf fans know what's up.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
printf "%02X;" {0..100}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation tested in KSH on OpenBSD (should work with any Bourne shell, doesn't rely on `bash` features).

```
#!/bin/sh

START=$1
END=$2

function h2d {
    echo "ibase=16; $@"|bc
}

function d2h {
    echo "obase=16; $@"|bc
}

# convert to decimal
START_DEC=`h2d ${START}`
END_DEC=`h2d ${END}`

# find length of last hex number
LENGTH=`expr ${#END} - 1`

for i in `nawk "BEGIN{ for(i=${START_DEC};i<=${END_DEC};i++) print i}"`
do
    # convert output to hex
    OUTPUT=`d2h ${i}`

    # calculate output length
    OUTPUT_LENGTH=`expr ${#OUTPUT}`

    # calculate required padding
    PAD_LENGTH=`expr ${LENGTH} - ${OUTPUT_LENGTH}`

    # output padding
    for j in `nawk "BEGIN{ for(j=0;j<=${PAD_LENGTH};j++) print j}"`
    do
        echo -n 0
    done

    # output number
    echo -n ${OUTPUT}\;
done

# for the newline
echo
```

Sample output:

```
    $ ./hex-range.sh 91 FF
91;92;93;94;95;96;97;98;99;9A;9B;9C;9D;9E;9F;A0;A1;A2;A3;A4;A5;A6;A7;A8;A9;AA;AB;AC;AD;AE;AF;B0;B1;B2;B3;B4;B5;B6;B7;B8;B9;BA;BB;BC;BD;BE;BF;C0;C1;C2;C3;C4;C5;C6;C7;C8;C9;CA;CB;CC;CD;CE;CF;D0;D1;D2;D3;D4;D5;D6;D7;D8;D9;DA;DB;DC;DD;DE;DF;E0;E1;E2;E3;E4;E5;E6;E7;E8;E9;EA;EB;EC;ED;EE;EF;F0;F1;F2;F3;F4;F5;F6;F7;F8;F9;FA;FB;FC;FD;FE;FF;
```

Regarding output to a text file, just use the shell redirection operator:

```
 $./hex-range.sh 91 FF > output.txt
```

Comment: Not quite bournish: The `function` reserved word is unknown to ancient sh. Use `h2d () { ...; }` instead.

Comment: Not just "ancient" sh -- it's not compliant with modern POSIX sh either.

Comment: Also, `echo -n` isn't specified by POSIX (or, rather, it's specified to have undefined behavior); `printf` is preferred instead. And `$(( ))` is both POSIX-defined and far more efficient than forking a subshell to run `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another implementation, which doesn't take all the original constraints into account (namely the zero padding and the semicolon separator), but might be useful to someone nevertheless:

```
bc <<< "obase=16; ibase=16; for (i = $low; i <= $high ; i++) i"
```

It avoids a separate fork by using a here-string (though even the more portable version of piping the string to `bc` isn't too bad), and then lets `bc` do all the computation and conversion.  You can remove `ibase=16` to allow for decimal inputs (and you can set `obase` to something else to have octal or binary or whatever).

Ideally, I think, this would all be built in to `seq`, though the documentation for the GNU version suggests that they'd rather you do it yourself:

> If you want hexadecimal integer output, you can use printf to perform the conversion:
>
> `$ printf '%x\n' $(seq 1048575 1024 1050623)`
>
> `fffff`
>
> `1003ff`
>
> `1007ff`

Answer (score 1):

`jot` can generate sequences of hexadecimal numbers in a given range:

```
$ jot -w %0.3x 20 20
014
015
016
017
018
019
01a
01b
01c
01d
01e
01f
020
021
022
023
024
025
026
027
```

It takes decimal form as the input though, so you would have to calculate the starting hex and how many numbers fit into the range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost there having picked through some simple commands and cobbled a very simple script together that pads properly and creates exactly the output I need:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Script to test for loop
i=10 #put start num in here
j=20 #put end num in here
for ((  a=i ;  a <= j;  a++  ))
do
printf '&#x%05x;' "$a" >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: While my version isn't optimized for brevity or speed, it does meet all of the stated requirements.  In particular, the dynamic padding based on the input, which isn't accounted for here (and is responsible for the length of the script).

Comment: This is not a Shell script. `for (( ... ))` is a non-portable shell extension (certainly not POSIX) and deviates from your original spec in that now the output is 0-padded to 5 digits no matter what the start and end numbers are, and prefixed with `&#`. It would have been better to state your actual requirements in the first place...

Comment: *nod* -- if you're going to use C-style `for` loops, use a shebang for a shell that's guaranteed to support them -- so not `#!/bin/sh` (which guarantees only POSIX compliance but no extensions), but `#!/bin/bash` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but here we go. I was just trying to create a file containing a sequence of bytes ranging from 0 to 255. Here is what I've got:

```
for n in $(seq 0 255); do printf "\x$(echo "obase=16; $n" | bc)" >> seq.bin; done
```

It is now exactly what was asked, but one can easily figure out how to change the command to do that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `seq` is not a POSIX-specified tool, and thus not guaranteed to be present and available.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that despite our love for our roots, sometimes it's not worth the pain. Considering the question involved inputting Hex, all the examples have the easiest way I know to deal with Hex in each Language, but my knowledge is pretty limited, so please do comment if you can think of better ways.

Point is: Use stff, especially the more common languages since they're probably already installed as dependencies pretty much everywhere... Never found a Computer without Ruby and/or Python, and now with Electron pretty much everyone also has NodeJS...

I used one-liners and included syntax to directly input from the terminal, the kinda stuff I save to cheatsheets and just copy-paste or type whenever I wanna use it

Ruby:

```
ruby -e "puts (0xA000..0xA0FF).to_a.join ';'"
```

I know my Ruby pretty well so that's what I'd use and why it's so pretty. For anyone who's not used to it, the `';'` at the end is used as an argument to join (And `puts` takes the whole thing as an argument). Dunno why there are still people who don't use Ruby...

Python (Not my thing and I'm too lazy to tackle joining list items without reduce, at least I hope it's just my laziness):

```
python -c 'from functools import reduce; print(reduce(lambda x,y: f"{x};{y}", range(0xA000, 0xA0FF)))'
```

And again, I REALLY hope this only sucks so much because I'm a Rubyist, 'cause I still hope Python will stop disappointing me someday...

JavaScript (Ok, I'll admit this is pretty awful):

```
node -e "n=0xA000,f=0xA0FF,r=[]; while(n<=f){r=r.concat(n);n++;};console.log(r.join(';'))"
```

It's possible to skip declaring `f` but it's not very helpful, plus makes it easier to get confused...

Lisp:

```
sbcl --noinform --quit --eval '(print (format nil "~{~A~^;~}" (loop for n from #xA000 below #xA0FF by #x01 collect n)))'
```

Not the prettiest or most concise but pretty readable except for LISP's `format` shit... I'll just stop here and hope Clojure, Scheme, Chicken, or whatever have better ways to deal with it...

Now Ruby is my main thing and I guess this fact as well as the reason why I love it is very obvious in this example: In Ruby, you do things the best way in a very concise and readable manner, no needless converting, importing stuff, declaring variables, etc. It just flows beautifully. <3

Since LISP is pretty low-level, you can compile it, it has Macros, there are lots of dialects, etc., it would be kinda Ok, especially if people's setups and/or dialects make things a beat cleaner, it's mostly the formatting stuff that feels really awful (Though the Loop is still too verbose IMHO, but then again dialects, macros, etc. can probably fix it).

Not gonna mention Python, again I really hope I'm the one lacking knowledge here because having to choose between a loop affecting an external variable versus importing stuff and using a Lambda for just a concatenation is something you should only have to think about in `C`, `LISP` and low-level stuff in general...

And Javascript, well, Javascript sucks, we all know it, and we love it anyway, so I guess this is a nice example of how shittily loveable JS is...

I probably should include a Perl version since it's the de facto Linux Language, but even if I'm not that great in Python, LISP and Javascript, I'm DEFINITELY not a Perl guy, so I'll leave it for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As @FernandoCoreiro pointed out in his answer, it is not very often than another, more evolved language, won't be installed, so rather than using shell, you can use for example `python` or php to generate it, and set it in a shell variable :

```
MY_SEQUENCE=$( *command* )
```

*command* being one of :

- in **Python**

  python -c 'print(";".join("%04X"%i for i in range(0xA000, 0xA0FF + 1)))'

`range(0xA000, 0xA0FF + 1)` generates the sequence from 40960 (0xA000) to 41215 (0xA0FF),
**Note** that you can enter the bounds in decimal or hexadecimal format. Writing 0xFF or 255 is equivalent.
**Note** that range doesn't include the upper bound, hence the `+ 1`

`"%04X"%i` formats each number of the sequence as a hexadecimal string (X means uppercase, use x for lowercase) with at least 4 digits,

`";".join()` concatenates all these strings,joining them with ";",

`printf` writes the result on the standard output.

- in **PHP**

  php -r 'echo implode(";", array_map(function($n) { return sprintf("%04X", $n); }, range(0xA000, 0xA0FF)));'

`range(0xA000, 0xA0FF)` generates the sequence from 40960 (0xA000) to 41215 (0xA0FF),
**Note** that you can enter the bounds in decimal or hexadecimal format. Writing 0xFF or 255 is equivalent.

`array_map()` applies the given function on each number of the sequence,

`function($n) { return sprintf("%04X", $n) }` formats the number as a hexadecimal string (X means uppercase, use x for lowercase) with at least 4 digits,

`implode(';', )` concatenates all these strings,joining them with ";",

`echo` writes the result on the standard output.

- see [Fernando Corerio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63200880/2955802) for other languages

Answer (score 0):

From 0h to fffh:

```
enum -w %0`expr length fff`x $(( 16#0 )) 1 $(( 16#fff ))
```

From fffh to 1200h:

```
enum -w %0`expr length 1200`x $(( 16#fff )) 1 $(( 16#1200 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seq 0x000 0xFFF | xargs printf '%03X;'
```

You would use the seq command to generate the decimal numbers then xargs to apply a transformation via printf.

Comment: It's generally nice to explain how your answer works, but this is an excellent answer otherwise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).